# open file in application vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, file-extension

So I have a text editor that I'm working on,  and It is an RTF editor, anyways, my custom file extension .swtf defaults to open my application, however if I do this it opens the application and there is not text in the Rich Text Box I was expecting this but now that I'm here I'd like to know how to make files opening my application Just open in Form1.RichTextBox1

Comment: are you processing the command line arguments?  So anyways, you should read this: [ask] and also take a look at this: [someone answers your question(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Using a default form instead of an instance of the form may be the issue. Please supply your code attempts.

Comment: This is what you have to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1